# Create pool of multiple SSL connections

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, connection, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have created secure LDAP connection following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17676476/420613) example using unboundid SDK.

I can create LDAPConnectionPool for unsecured servers using following code.

```
LDAPConnectionPool connectionPool = new LDAPConnectionPool(serverSet, bindRequest, 10);
```

How can I create LDAPConnectionPool for more than one servers(ldap and ldaps) i.e. both secure and unsecured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Serverset` in

`LDAPConnectionPool connectionPool = new LDAPConnectionPool(serverSet, bindRequest, 10);` can set `socketFactory`

so whatever your server set is "failoverSet" or "roundRobinSet" it can set socketfactory in its constructor like

```
roundRobinSet = new RoundRobinServerSet(addresses, ports, socketFactory);
```